# Object parameter used in the same object as other object parameter?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Fast simply newbie question - it is possible to use object parameter in other object parameter (but it is the same object)?

```
var obj = {
  a : 'a',
  b : 'b',
  ab : 'Our new parameter: ' + (obj.a + obj.b) + 'is presented!',
  test : obj.ab
}

console.log(obj.ab);
```

So object is not ready when I call obj.ab - any idea how handle this?
**obj** is global object now and rest of the code are using heavy of obj.ab - I don;t want to make significant changes, any simple idea?

Comment: I did find there some guidance, so I did manage to accomplish what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to simple convert to a function `ab` and access the object properties through `this`.

```js
var obj = {
  a : 'a',
  b : 'b',
  ab : () => 'Our new parameter: ' + (this.obj.a + this.obj.b) + 'is presented!',
  test : () => this.obj.ab
};

console.log(obj.ab());
console.log(obj.test());

// ab: () => is an arrow function
// test: () => is also an arrow function
```

Comment: thanks I did something similar at the end: var foo = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: function(){return foo.a + foo.b;}(),
    d: function(){return foo.c;}()
}

console.log(foo.c); // ab
console.log(foo.d); // ab
console.log(foo); // our foo object show proper values

Comment: Awesome, that way is also correct!

Comment: not really... it does not work when I export my globals object and I dunno why. No matter if I use object or this it simply do not work - gives undefined. EDIT: it worked when I execute the function (method) in file that require the globals. So methods in globals object must NOT be invoked.

Comment: I see, I recommend you take a look to Module Pattern https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript to avoid those problems

Comment: Bahhh I think this case is even more specific.... I have globals object inside route (express routes), and at the end it turn out I need instances of my globals object - otherwise app do not work properly. So any idea how to have instance of globals object - accessible through all modules that require it (connected to specific user request - so every user have... someking of own globals object)? Thanks for the link anyway!